# Servicestack - Multiple IReturn on Request DTO

Tags: c#, servicestack, swagger-ui, servicestack-bsd

Is it possible to have multiple `IReturn<>` on a request DTO?

For example following route:

```cs
[Route("/api/whatever", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE")]
public class WhateverRequest : IReturn<bool>, IReturn<List<Whatever>>
{
    public string WhateverId { get; set; }
}
```

Depending on the request method I want to have another `IReturn`.
Post-Put-Delete Request should only return a acknowledge if the request was successful:

```cs
IReturn<bool>
```

but on a GET request I want to have a:

```cs
IReturn<List<Whatever>>
```

It would also be good if there is a way to reflect this in Swagger Api/ Metadata Page.
Currently only the first `IReturn` is shown.

Is this possible or would it be better to create a route for each different `IReturn`?

Comment: Caribertl did you manage to sort this using individual routes?

Comment: Scott, Thank you very much! I changed my code to have different routes for each return type. Now I have a `WhateverGetRequest`, `WhateverPostRequest` ... This way the metadata/swagger pages also show only the parameters that are needed for each route. Also thanks for the tip with `IReturnVoid`

Comment: You're welcome. That's great you have it working. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to be creating different routes to handle the multiple return types. Only one `IReturn<T>` or `IReturnVoid` is expected, or consuming clients wouldn't know how to type the returned data correctly.

```
[Route("/api/whatever", "GET")]
public class ListWhateverRequest : IReturn<List<Whatever>>
{
    public string WhateverId { get; set; }
}

// Action
public List<Whatever> Get(ListWhateverRequest request)
{
    ...
}

[Route("/api/whatever", "POST,PUT,DELETE")]
public class UpdateWhateverRequest : IReturn<bool>
{
    public string WhateverId { get; set; }
}

// Action
public bool Post(UpdateWhateverRequest request)
{
    ...
}

public bool Put(UpdateWhateverRequest request)
{
    ...
}

public bool Delete(UpdateWhateverRequest request)
{
    ...
}
```

---

I presume you are returning `true` from these methods to show they completed successfully. Do the methods ever return `false` when something goes wrong, or is an exception thrown instead? If you are only throwing exception in the method, and never returning false then instead of returning `bool` consider using `void` methods with `IReturnVoid`. The request is therefore successful if it doesn't throw an exception.